# How can I remove the underline on my coverletter?

Tags: formatting, koma-script, letters

I'm following along here:

http://www.kindoblue.nl/articles/cover-letter-part3/

```
\documentclass[standard,a4paper, pagesize,backaddress=plain]{scrlttr2}    
%\usepackage[english]{babel} 
\begin{document}    
\begin{letter}{    
    Title   \\%    
    Company \\%    
    Adress      \\%    
    City, State Zip
}    
\setkomavar{subject}{Cover Letter}    
\opening{Dear Recruiter,}    
My name is John bla bla bla ...    
\closing{Regards}    
\end{letter}    
\end{document}
```

---

This is what I have, but I get the address from standard.lco to print out like this:

Name, Address, City, State Zip, USA

However, it is underlined... How do I make it so it's like the author of this tutorial?

---

Here is the `.lco` file I am using:

```
\ProvidesFile{standard.lco}[%    
    2002/07/09 v0.9a LaTeX2e unsupported letter-class-option]    
%\usepackage[english]{babel}    
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{fix-cm} 
\usepackage{marvosym}
% ==================================================    
% PERSONAL DATA
% ==================================================
\setkomavar{fromname}{name}
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{address\\city, state zip\\USA}
\setkomavar{fromphone}{phone number}
\setkomavar{fromemail}{email address}
\setkomavar{place}{city}
\setkomavar{signature}{name}
% ==================================================
% FORMATTING
% ==================================================
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\setmainfont{Tahoma}
\setsansfont{Verdana}
\renewcommand{\normalsize}{\fontsize{11}{16}\selectfont}
\newcommand\myname{%
    {\addfontfeature{LetterSpace=15.0}\fontsize{36}{36}\selectfont\scshape \usekomavar{fromname}}
}
\newcommand\mytitle{%
    \fontsize{21}{21}\selectfont\scshape occupation
}
\setkomavar{firsthead}{
    \centering
        \myname\\[5mm]
        \mytitle
}
\setkomavar{firstfoot}{
    \centering
    \addfontfeature{LetterSpace=20.0}\scshape
    {\renewcommand{\\}{\ {\large\textperiodcentered}\ }
    \usekomavar{fromaddress}\\
    {\Large\Letter} \usekomavar{fromemail} \ {\Large\Telefon} \usekomavar{fromphone}
}   
\endinput
```

---

At the current time, I get the following error:

```
Runaway argument?
{ \centering \addfontfeature {LetterSpace=20.0}\scshape {\renewcommand \ETC.
! File ended while scanning use of \@@setkomavar.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.3 \begin
          {document}
?
```

Why does this error occur?

Comment: Can you supply us with a visual of your output, as it does not show with an underline when I compile your minimal document.

Comment: Yes, @Werner, see my edit. Notice that I edited the first block of code.

Comment: Can you remove the spurious blank lines?

Comment: What blank lines?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: @AardWolf: The ones I removed. :-)

Answer (score 3):

Add the option `backaddress=plain`, as explained on page 172 of the current documentation:

```
\documentclass[
  standard,
  a4paper,
  pagesize,
  backaddress=plain,
]{scrlttr2}
```

(this way of typing options is handier because it clearly shows all of them).

[image]

The error is because you're missing a closing brace:

```
\setkomavar{firstfoot}{
    \centering
    \addfontfeature{LetterSpace=20.0}\scshape
    {\renewcommand{\\}{\ {\large\textperiodcentered}\ }}%<----- Here it was missing
    \usekomavar{fromaddress}\\
    {\Large\Letter} \usekomavar{fromemail} \ {\Large\Telefon} \usekomavar{fromphone}
}
```

Comment: I want it like this though: http://www.kindoblue.nl/images/sample_letter_step54.png

Comment: What does this have to do with your question?

Comment: "How do I make it so it's like the author of this tutorial?"

Comment: @AardWolf Well, copy the `.lco` from there.